# Hide rows based on week's date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with 5 named columns.

Under "Recursive_Requests" column, it's shown 1 of the 8 possible options (every_day , every_monday , every_tuesday , every_wednesday , every_thursday , every_friday , every_saturday , No).
The sheet is organized following the options' order under the "Department" column (flagged in **bold**).

Every day at 9am, the sheet would check if the option under "Recursive_Requests" column matches with today's date. If it doesn't match, it'd hide the row until the requirement is met (adding or removing empty rows if they are useful or not to sort the sheet).

"every_day" and "no" are always showed.

I've read and tried other threads, but none are completely similar ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088049/google-sheets-hide-rows-based-on-todays-date), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535729/google-apps-script-that-hides-row-if-a-date-is-less-than-or-equal-to-todays-dat) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069149/google-script-how-to-hide-a-row-if-a-cell-contains-a-date-10-days-older-than-to), for example).

I've tried also to filter and show rows (but this doesn't work with dates):

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("filter")
    .addItem("rows_filter", "filter_rows")
    .addItem("rows_show", "show_rows")
    .addToUi();
}

function filter_rows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(row_name[2] === "every_monday") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function show_rows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  sheet.show_rows(1, sheet.getMaxRows());
}
```

e.g.:

Before any edit:

| Timestamp | Name | Department | Request | Recursive_Requests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26/10/2022 19.05.24 | John | **first_department** | second_request | No |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.05.38 | Alexander | **second_department** | first_request | every_tuesday |
| 26/10/2022 19.07.56 | Wayne | **second_department** | third_request | every_monday |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.09.36 | Robert | **third_department** | first_request | every_tuesday |
| 26/10/2022 19.11.19 | Larry | **third_department** | second_request | every_thursday |
| 26/10/2022 19.11.51 | Jared | **third_department** | third_request | every_wednesday |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.13.41 | Peter | **fourth_department** | first_request | every_saturday |
| 26/10/2022 19.14.58 | Tom | **fourth_department** | fourth_request | every_day |

If it's Monday (after editing):

| Timestamp | Name | Department | Request | Recursive_Requests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26/10/2022 19.05.24 | John | **first_department** | second_request | No |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.07.56 | Wayne | **second_department** | third_request | every_monday |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.14.58 | Tom | **fourth_department** | fourth_request | every_day |

If it's Tuesday (after editing):

| Timestamp | Name | Department | Request | Recursive_Requests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26/10/2022 19.05.24 | John | **first_department** | second_request | No |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.05.38 | Alexander | **second_department** | first_request | every_tuesday |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.09.36 | Robert | **third_department** | first_request | every_tuesday |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.14.58 | Tom | **fourth_department** | fourth_request | every_day |

If it's Wednesday (after editing):

| Timestamp | Name | Department | Request | Recursive_Requests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26/10/2022 19.05.24 | John | **first_department** | second_request | No |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.11.51 | Jared | **third_department** | third_request | every_wednesday |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.14.58 | Tom | **fourth_department** | fourth_request | every_day |

If it's Thursday (after editing):

| Timestamp | Name | Department | Request | Recursive_Requests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26/10/2022 19.05.24 | John | **first_department** | second_request | No |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.11.19 | Larry | **third_department** | second_request | every_thursday |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.14.58 | Tom | **fourth_department** | fourth_request | every_day |

If it's Friday (after editing):

| Timestamp | Name | Department | Request | Recursive_Requests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26/10/2022 19.05.24 | John | **first_department** | second_request | No |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.14.58 | Tom | **fourth_department** | fourth_request | every_day |

If it's Saturday (after editing):

| Timestamp | Name | Department | Request | Recursive_Requests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26/10/2022 19.05.24 | John | **first_department** | second_request | No |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.13.41 | Peter | **fourth_department** | first_request | every_saturday |
| 26/10/2022 19.14.58 | Tom | **fourth_department** | fourth_request | every_day |

If it's Sunday (after editing):

| Timestamp | Name | Department | Request | Recursive_Requests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26/10/2022 19.05.24 | John | **first_department** | second_request | No |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 26/10/2022 19.14.58 | Tom | **fourth_department** | fourth_request | every_day |

Instead the output I get with the current Query () is (if it's Monday):

| Timestamp | Name | Department | Request | Recursive_Requests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26/10/2022 19.05.24 | John | **first_department** | second_request | No |
| 26/10/2022 19.07.56 | Wayne | **second_department** | third_request | every_monday |
| 26/10/2022 19.14.58 | Tom | **fourth_department** | fourth_request | every_day |

Basically there aren't blank rows between differents departments to visually order the sheet.

Currently: it isn't able to discriminate between different days / hide rows accordingly / it can't add or remove empty rows to organize the sheet / check this condition every day at 9am.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: I've added the table.

Comment: Please show very simply the “before” and “after” you desire as compared to the “after” you are currently achieving.

Comment: I've added before & after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can easily be resolved with a query formula (Answer to original question):

```
=Query({A:E}, "select * where Col5 = 'No' or Col5 = 'every_day' or Col5 = '"& switch(weekday(today()),2,"every_monday",3,"every_tuesday",4,"every_wednesday",5,"every_thursday",6,"every_friday",7,"every_saturday","every_sunday")&"'",1)
```

Replace A:E with the reference to your original table and you can replace today() with a cell reference containing a date if you don’t want to use today’s date. Make sure this query formula has enough space to the right and bottom to populate.

In the comments below you made an additional request of showing four departments with a blank line between each query:

```
={Query({A:E}, "select * where Col3 = 'first_department' and ( Col5 = 'No' or Col5 = 'every_day' or Col5 = '"& switch(weekday(today()),2,"every_monday",3,"every_tuesday",4,"every_wednesday",5,"every_thursday",6,"every_friday",7,"every_saturday","every_sunday")&"')",1); "","","","","";
iferror(Query({A:E}, "select * where Col3 = 'second_department' and ( Col5 = 'No' or Col5 = 'every_day' or Col5 = '"& switch(weekday(today()),2,"every_monday",3,"every_tuesday",4,"every_wednesday",5,"every_thursday",6,"every_friday",7,"every_saturday","every_sunday")&"')",0),{"","","","",""}); "","","","","";
iferror(Query({A:E}, "select * where Col3 = 'third_department' and ( Col5 = 'No' or Col5 = 'every_day' or Col5 = '"& switch(weekday(today()),2,"every_monday",3,"every_tuesday",4,"every_wednesday",5,"every_thursday",6,"every_friday",7,"every_saturday","every_sunday")&"')",0),{"","","","",""}); "","","","","";
iferror(Query({A:E}, "select * where Col3 = 'fourth_department' and ( Col5 = 'No' or Col5 = 'every_day' or Col5 = '"& switch(weekday(today()),2,"every_monday",3,"every_tuesday",4,"every_wednesday",5,"every_thursday",6,"every_friday",7,"every_saturday","every_sunday")&"')",0),{"","","","",""}); "","","","",""}
```

The reason why we need an iferror in the queries without a header is the formula will fail without it due to a blank output.

Comment: Thanks indeed. The code you provided me can check the condition every 24h based on the row's "Timestamp" value? Most importantly, the answers remain on the sheet, they are only hidden?

Comment: @MichaelBenton you will leave your original table untouched and make your edits there and make a new sheet called filtered_table or something like that which will contain this formula and is basically for display and printing purposes only. The query will update in real time and the way it is currently set up it will show you Monday on Monday and it will automatically change to Tuesday on Tuesday at midnight. You could add +1 after today() to see tomorrow for example.

Comment: @MichaelBenton is what I wrote above clear enough? Your timestamp values are all very similar so I’m not sure exactly what you want to do with that as opposed to just using the actual date in real time.

Comment: This because my "day" has to start at 10:00am of a day and end at 09:59am of the day after. I don't know if I explained 100% clearly, so tell me in case.

Comment: @MichaelBenton 1) if your objective is to not email the hidden rows then why not just email the second query sheet 2) the query formula will run in real time not every 24 hours, isn’t that better?

Comment: 1) oh, ok. So the 2nd sheet will be updated in real-time to look like an exact copy of the 1st one? 2) to be fair, I'm still not convinced. The requests on the sheet are considered "a part of one day" if their "Timestamp" value falls between 10:00am of a day and 10:00am of the day after. But your query thinks that at midnight it begins another day, for me it's all shifted (my "midnight" is at 10:00am).

Comment: @MichaelBenton just add or subtract from the today() function for example you could add 0.5 to push half a day forward.

Comment: @MichaelBenton first make sure importrange is working for you at all, I recommend creating a sheet specifically for importrange and then using the query on that in a second sheet. What error are you getting? Make sure to put the query in a blank sheet in cell A1

Comment: Importrange alone works very well. The "#ERROR!" raises when I paste you query in the sheet. I've noticed that Google Sheets suggests me to use the form "QUERY(data ; query ; [headers])" with the semicolons. Maybe that's the cause. Has Google Sheets been updated recently? I'll add my edited code in an answer.

Comment: @MichaelBenton you need to replace A:E with the actual cell reference to your table. You should delete your answer as that is not an appropriate place to put your code that is not working. You have “A:E” as a string and not a cell reference which would just be A:E also don’t put the import range in the query function as that is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @MichaelBenton you need to use semi colons instead of commas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65841929/any-idea-why-this-formula-would-through-an-error-on-google-sheets/65846001#65846001

Comment: @MichaelBenton I don’t have any specific cell reference in my original formula, A:E is what I put if you are using B:E then you are missing a column from your original data

Comment: I'm putting your Query() only in the "E" column (Recursive_Requests), referencing only the "E" column from the original sheet. From column "A" to "D" i used a simple sheet referencing. If I had left your Query() from column "A" to "E", my alias-sheet would have been static (didn't update with the original). How to solve?

Comment: @MichaelBenton I have test data (identical to what you provided in the question) which the formula is working perfectly for me, you’ll have to share a sheet similar enough so that I can see what you are talking about. It’s actually hard to create a static query that’s not the normal behavior.

Comment: I've tried on a new blank sheet and your Query() works well. Maybe it was a problem with the older sheet. As a final addition, it'd be useful if your Query() left untouched the already-existent blank rows (of the first sheet) in the "filtered" sheet.

Comment: @MichaelBenton what do you mean left untouched already blank rows?

Comment: @MichaelBenton the query doesn’t change your original data so I’m not sure what the problem is you are describing, you want to have blank rows in your query output?

Comment: @CodeCamper I'd want that your Query() separated the different "Departments" with a blank row, similarly to the sheet before any edits. Please look carefully my first post: I've edited it to make my issue as clear as possible. For any question, feel free to ask!

Comment: @MichaelBenton do you have a fixed number of departments? This is very trivial you would just combine together multiple queries for each department with a hard coded blank line.

Comment: @CodeCamper Yes I've got 4 fixed departments, but each department can contain a varying number of users (e.g.: it depends on how many people choose the "second_department" option, every day the number changes). How would multiple queries be combined together? Would they update the sheet in sync?

Comment: @MichaelBenton Yes, see updated answer on the bottom. Please be aware that your question was already answered and it is becoming multiple questions. You should mark this as the answer if it works per your original question and then if you have an additional programming question it really should be a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. Your Query() works perfectly: problem solved! I apologize if I caused chaos by asking multiple questions under the same thread, I'll keep your suggestion in mind for the future :)

Answer (score 2):

Show Hide:

```
function showhide00() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtday = dt.getDay();
  const aObj = { "every_day": { "v": "show" }, "every_monday": { "day": 1 }, "every_tuesday": { "day": 2 }, "every_wednesday": { "day": 3 }, "every_thursday": { "day": 4 }, "every_friday": { "day": 5 }, "every_saturday": { "day": 6 }, "No": { "v": "show" } }
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let day = new Date(r[0]).getDay();
    if (aObj[r[4]].hasOwnProperty("v") && aObj[r[4]].v == "show" || aObj[r[4]].hasOwnProperty("day") && aObj[r[4]]["day"] == dtday) {
      sh.showRows(i + 2)
    } else {
      sh.hideRows(i + 2)
    }
  })

}
```

SheetO (before):

| Timestamp | Name | Department | Request | Recursive_Requests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17/10/2022 17.05.24 | John | first_department | second_request | No |
| 17/10/2022 17.05.38 | Alexander | third_department | second_request | every_monday |
| 17/10/2022 17.05.58 | Tom | third_department | first_request | every_day |
|  |  |  |  | every_tuesday |
|  |  |  |  | every_wednesday |
|  |  |  |  | every_thursday |
|  |  |  |  | every_friday |
|  |  |  |  | every_saturday |

Sheet0 (After): today is a Wednesday

| Timestamp | Name | Department | Request | Recursive_Requests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17/10/2022 17.05.24 | John | first_department | second_request | No |
| 17/10/2022 17.05.38 | Alexander | third_department | second_request | every_monday |
| 17/10/2022 17.05.58 | Tom | third_department | first_request | every_day |
|  |  |  |  | every_tuesday |
|  |  |  |  | every_wednesday |

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, the sheet has to show only "every_day", "No" and the option matching the current day. I've updated the first post to make things easier.